# How to store a string into HashMap using StringTokenizer

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

```
String input = "key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3&key4=value4&key5=value5";
```

How can I store the key-value pairs into a `HashMap` object using `StringTokenizer`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a StringTokenizer would look something like this I guess.

```
String input = "key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3&key4=value4&key5=value5";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input, "&");

Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

while ( st.hasMoreElements() ) {

    String actualElement = st.nextToken();
    StringTokenizer et = new StringTokenizer(actualElement, "=");

    if ( et.countTokens() != 2 ) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unexpeced format");
    }

    String key = et.nextToken();
    String value = et.nextToken();

    map.put(key, value);
}

System.out.println(map);
```

You could also use String.split(). It looks a little nicer in my opinion.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

for ( String actualElement : input.split("&") ) {
    map.put(actualElement.split("=")[0],
            actualElement.split("=")[1]);
}

System.out.println(map);
```

Beware that you must make sure that the delimiters (in this case "=" and "&") is not allowed to appear in the data! When the delimiters should be allowed to appear in the data they must be escaped in some way to handle the input properly.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that initial question was referring to the usage of `StringTokenizer` but it can be done with `Splitter` from guava in a more easier and concise way:

```
Map<String, String> map = ImmutableMap.copyOf(Splitter.on('&')
.withKeyValueSeparator("=")
.split(checkNotNull(input)));
```